# How to Track Visitors Comming from Adwords and Disable form fields that is not on landing page

Tags: google, google-ads, cookie

There is a lead form on my website where we track from which source visitors have arrived. I wanted to disable the drop down and auto populate it with predefined data if the visitor is from adwords. This form is not on the landing page. Is there a way I could do that by reading cookie or any other way.

Comment: Backend language on the website is PHP

Answer (score 1):

In php exists variable which can help you: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. [Just see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613025/how-can-i-use-serverhttp-referer-to-find-that-user-came-from-google).

Comment: You can also do it based on the url.  Adwords can add tracking urls that look like UTM_Source / UTM_Campaign.  You can use PHP or even javascript to read these values and tweak your landing page. Or you can create a custom landing page based on each referral.  This might be a good investment.  If you can really understand your audience, having multiple landing pages for different campaigns targeted for different audiences will pay off.   For example on landing page for customers googling your competition.  One landing page for people searching "lowest price ...."